# Calling python function in server from local machine using angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, cgi

I am having problem in calling a python function with  angularjs $http request.
I am having a python function which is on server like this

```
import cgi, cgitb
data= cgi.FieldStorage()
name = data.getvalue("name");
age = data.getvalue("age");
def printinfo( name, age ):
    print "Name: ", name
    print "Age ", age
    return name,age
```

and i've also included cgi and my javascript code is

```
 angular.module('app1',[])
 .controller('ctrl',['$scope','$http' ,function ($scope,$http) {

 $scope.bin = 'examp';
 $scope.go = function () {
        var url = "http://localhost/dump/test/test.py";

   var bad =$http({
            url :url ,
            method:'POST',
            data:{"name":"kumar" , "age":21}
        }).success(function(data){
         alert("working");
       });
    }

 }])
```

and my javascript code is able to make a call to http://localhost/dump/test/test.py but it is shown as a document even when i included cgi in it ..
Please guide me and also can you guys tell me is it the right way to send the values to server ie can i invoke the function print info by just sending name and age or should i send the function name too. If yes let me know how can i pass it ..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

May be your webserver do not know how to handle .py files. You need to configure webserver to handle python. Try the below if  it is not configured.

https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/129-servers/757148-configuring-apache2-to-run-python-scripts

But a more good approach is to create a web app using some python framework and expose urls via a web server.  If you are interested in that then I would recommend you to learn flask python framework.

Comment: i've done these changes in my apache config file and created a sample python file used in that example but still it is shown as text in browser.